# Vaciar cola en matrices en Java

Tags: java, matrices, booleano, queue

He estado haciendo un código que solicita lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El ejemplo que marca debería ser así:

Llega P1:

Cola:

[P1]

Llega P2:

Cola:

[P1, P2]

Atendiendo a P1:
P1 es Estudiante, Número de Caja 1, Monto a Pagar: $20. Sala escogida: 1

Y luego se imprimiría la matriz donde la persona eligió(de forma aleatoria) su asiento.

En mi código hice tres matrices y una cola, y de acuerdo a lo que llevo hecho, debería realizar lo del ejemplo, pero tengo tres problemas:

No sé cómo puedo hacer que se empiecen a agregar los elementos de la
cola(Ya sé cómo funciona) de forma aleatoria a la matriz. Pensaba que haciendo dos ciclos for para la matriz y colocar de forma aleatoria la posición de la misma lo arreglaría, pero no:

```
for (int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrix[0].length; x++) {
                matrix[ rand.nextInt (matrix.length) ] [ rand.nextInt (matrix[0].length) ] = people.poll();
            }
        }
```

2. Y tampoco sé cómo evitar que se repita la posición ocupada.
3. No sé exáctamente cómo hacer que, al llenarse una matriz, ésta deje de aceptar personas y solamente deje llenar las restantes. Traté con un booleano pero tampoco salía como debía, usando este ejemplo de código para explicar lo que quería hacer:

   ```
    int[][] matrix = new int[5][rand.nexInt(3)+5];

    int desocupados = matrix.length * matrix[0].length;

    boolean follow = true;

    if (follow) {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrix[0].length; x++) {
                matrix[ rand.nextInt (matrix.length) ] [ rand.nextInt (matrix[0].length) ] = people.poll();
                desocupados--;
            }
        }

        if (desocupados == 0)
        follow = false;
    }
   ```

Lo que llevo de código es lo siguiente:

```
private static Random r = new Random();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Integer> people = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int[][] room1 = new int[5][r.nextInt(3)+5];
    int[][] room2 = new int[5][r.nextInt(3)+5];
    int[][] room3 = new int[5][r.nextInt(3)+5];

    String[] age = {"Estudiante", "Adulto", "Adulto Mayor"};
    int age1 = 20, age2 = 35, age3 = 25;

    boolean follow = true;

    int n = 1; //Contar número de la persona que ingrese a la cola
    while (follow) { //iniciar el proceso de la cola y selección de asientos
        boolean room1NotFull = true; //Validar si la sala no se ha llenado aún
        boolean room2NotFull = true; //Validar si la sala no se ha llenado aún
        boolean room3NotFull = true; //Validra si la sala no se ha llenado aún

        while (room1NotFull && room2NotFull && room3NotFull) { //Mientras las tres salas no esten llenas, comenzar a llenarlas
            n = makeQueue(people, n);
            int price = 0;
            int whatAge = r.nextInt(3)+0;
            switch (whatAge) {
                case 0: price = age1; break;
                case 1: price = age2; break;
                case 2: price = age3; break; 
            }
            int chooseRoom = r.nextInt(3)+1;

            int cashier = r.nextInt(3)+1;

            switch (cashier) { //Cada cashier es una caja
                case 1://CAJA 1
                System.out.println("Atendiendo a P"+people.peek());
                System.out.println("P"+ people.peek() +" es "+ age[whatAge] +", Número de caja "+ cashier +", Monto a pagar: $"+ price +". Sala escogida: "+ chooseRoom);
                switch (chooseRoom) { //Dentro de cada caja, se puede "elegir" una sala (aleatoriamente)
                    case 1:
                    fillingRoom1(room1, people);
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    fillingRoom2(room2, people);
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    fillingRoom3(room3, people);
                    break;
                }
                break;

                case 2://CAJA 2
                System.out.println("Atendiendo a P"+people.peek()); 
                System.out.println("P"+ people.peek() +" es "+ age[whatAge] +", Número de caja "+ cashier +", Monto a pagar: $"+ price +". Sala escogida: "+ chooseRoom );
                switch (chooseRoom) { //Dentro de cada caja, se puede "elegir" una sala (aleatoriamente)
                    case 1:
                    fillingRoom1(room1, people);
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    fillingRoom2(room2, people);
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    fillingRoom3(room3, people);
                    break;
                }
                break;

                case 3://CAJA 3
                System.out.println("Atendiendo a P"+people.peek());
                System.out.println("P"+ people.peek() +" es "+ age[whatAge] +", Número de caja "+ cashier +", Monto a pagar: $"+ price +". Sala escogida: "+ chooseRoom);
                switch (chooseRoom) { //Dentro de cada caja, se puede "elegir" una sala (aleatoriamente)
                    case 1:
                    fillingRoom1(room1, people);
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    fillingRoom2(room2, people);
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    fillingRoom3(room3, people);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
}

//CREAR LA COLA
private static int makeQueue(Queue<Integer> people, int n) {
    int P = (n++);
    int P2 = (n++);
    //Al agregar a la cola, lo estaré haciendo de dos en dos
    System.out.println("Llega P"+ P);
    people.offer(P); //Añadir a la cola
    System.out.println("Llega P"+ P2);
    people.offer(P2); //Añadir a la cola
    return printQueue(people, n);
}
//IMPRIMIR LA COLA
private static int printQueue(Queue<Integer> people, int n) {
    System.out.println("COLA: ");
    for (int e : people)
    System.out.println(" [P"+ e+"] ");
    return n;
}

//LLENAR LA SALA 1
public static void fillingRoom1(int[][] matrix, Queue<Integer> people) {
}

//LLENAR LA SALA 2
public static void fillingRoom2(int[][] matrix, Queue<Integer> people) {
}

//LLENAR LA SALA 3
public static void fillingRoom3(int[][] matrix, Queue<Integer> people) {
}

//IMPRIMIR LAS SALAS
public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++) {
        for (int  y = 0; y < matrix[0].length; x++) {
            if (matrix[x][y] != 0) { //Si existen valores que no sean iguales a cero, imprimir de esta forma
                String val = String.format("%2s", matrix[x][y]);
                System.out.print(" ["+ val +"] ");
            } else { //Si hay ceros, colocar corchetes vacíos
                System.out.println(" [  ] ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Todavía soy muy novato en java. Desearía más que nada recomendaciones para mi código, y si tienen alguna otra alternativa a lo que llevo realizado, estaría bien.

Por el momento, esto es lo que imprime la consola:

[image]

Comment: Antes de escribir una respuesta: ¿No crees que sería mejor usar orientación a objetos? Crear una clase Sala, una clase Asiento, una clase Persona, una clase Taquilla... y que cada una se encargue de su parte. Usar una matriz para los asientos lo considero innecesario, yo crearía una lista de Asientos con fila, columa y persona como atributos, siendo esta última null cuando está vacío

Comment: Mi profesor me pidió que en este ejercicio evitaramos manejar clases  y lo menor que se pueda relacionado a POO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que has complejizado demasiado tu ejercicio, cuando tenias que seguir los pasos paso a paso.

No voy a resolver tu ejercicio, pero si marcarte todas las cosas que estan raras:

La funcion makeQueue para empezar hace cosas raras:

- recibe un n que es el numero de la persona a agregar.
- hace dos veces lo mismo, en lugar de usar un iterador (por ejemplo un for)
- Devuelve el ultimo numero agregado
- Llama a imprimir cola, lo cual estaria mal porque la funcion que agrega no deberia imprimir (esto seria solamente como buena practica)

Deberia ser algo asi:

```
private static int makeQueue(Queue<Integer> people, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2;i++)
    {
        n++;
        System.out.println("Llega P"+ n);
        people.offer(n); //Añadir a la cola
    }
    //Lo que sigue no deberia estar aca, pero lo dejamos solo para simplificar
    return printQueue(people, n+2);
}
```

Las 3 variables edad no tienen sentido:

Si tenes un array para las edades, entonces tambien tenes un array para los precios, y los dos usan el mismo indice...

cambia:

```
int age1 = 20, age2 = 35, age3 = 25;
```

Por

```
int[] age = {20,35,25}
```

y cuando obtenes el numero random para la edad, quedate con el mismo para el precio y usa la misma posicion para los dos.

No tiene sentido tener 3 funciones fillingRoomX que hacen exactamente lo mismo... Usa una sola funcion que reciba la sala a llenar

Luego, para elegir la caja, tampoco tiene sentido hacer un switch.. si eligio la caja, eso es solo una variable para tu print... pero todos funcionan igual...

Y luego, tu mayor problema que es llenar el asiento. Como las personas entran de a una, no necesitas recorrer toda la matriz.
Tu mejor opcion es que la matriz este toda en cero al empezar (para eso si usa el for que escribiste, con las tres matices) y luego de eso para saber si un asiento esta vacio, podes fijarte si vale cero. Si no vale cero, elegi otra fila y columna. Ojo porque este proceso, cuando la sala este casi llena, puede llegar a ser muy lento porque las posiciones que te toquen se pueden repetir....

Cuando la persona se sienta, cambias el valor al numero de personsa sentada.

Para guardar la cantidad de gente por sala, usa un array que guarde la info de la cantidad de personas, dependiendo el tipo, usando la misma logica que para las edades.

Y tu problema no es de java, es de algoritmos ;)